# How to attach debugger to service or app immediatelly after device reboot?

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea

I am testing a few services which have to be started even if device restarts. Now, if I attach debugger to an app, it gets disconnected when device goes off. And it does not reattached when device fully boots up.

I am missing something I am sure. Please help...

To clarify, I need to attach to the process the second it's started after device boot. This cannot be done in a way that I press Debug button manually after a device restarts.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your service code where you want to debug:

```
android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
```

Put a breakpoint after this. Make sure Eclipse is running. Reboot your device with it attached to your computer. Once the service starts and hits the waitForDebugger, Eclipse will break into debug mode.

Comment: the question was "how to attach to a running process"

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the full solution to your problem, but when your device restarts, go to the  "Devices" tab in Eclipse, and select or reselect your device. When you switch back to the logcat tab, you should now see the logs of your device. I guess that could help to test your service.